# Why does OpenJDK place private methods into vtable?

Tags: jvm, bytecode, java

It seems that [openJDK 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/klassVtable.cpp#l575) places private methods which are not `final` nor `static` into vtable. Why is it so when dynamic binding is not used for private methods (since they're invoked with [invokespecial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial)) or is it used?

Comment: What do you mean by "vtable"? This isn't C++.

Comment: But the implementation is similar to C++, the difference is that vtables are computed when the program is running by the linker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done to handle some rare situations when an overridable method with the same name and signature exists in a superclass. Though there is definitely a place for improvement, may be, targeted for JDK 9.

See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8024368

> Private methods always get a vtable entry to handle backward
>   compatibility  with classes - i.e. you can have the same name of a
>   private method local to your class and also inherit a method of from
>   your superclass, which will get inherited around the private method,
>   by your child.

Comment: So when a private method is called its vtable entry is never used?

Comment: @RadekMicek Right, this entry is not used in method calls.

Comment: I thought it over and over and still don’t get it. First, I don’t get which actual behavior should be achieved and second, every possible behavior that I can imagine could be implemented without adding `private` methods to the vTable.

Comment: As I understand it, it is needed by the code which builds vtables (maybe it makes that code simpler??) - but this is purely my speculation.